# Rails 3: Only show the first image from the Database

Tags: image, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using rails 3.

In my database I have several tables that work together using one common column "property_id" to relate them. In my property_images table, there are several images with the same property_id. I use the following code to show all the images in the property/show page.

```
<% for image in @property.property_images %>
    <%= image_tag image.image_url %>
<%end%>
```

I'd like to be able to display only the first image for the property_id in another area on that page. Does anyone know how I'd write the logic for that in the controller and place it in the property/show page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like this.

```
<%= image_tag @property.property_images.first.image_url %>
```

Since `property_images` is just an array...

Answer (score 0):

```
<% for image in @property.property_images.limit(1) %>
<%= image_tag image.image_url %>
```

<%end%>